# How can I tell using reflection if a class is final

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose I have a class:

`public final class Foo`

and a reflected `Class clz` reference that refers to that class.

How can I tell (using `clz`) that `Foo` is `final`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using [`Class#getModifiers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers--):

```
Modifier.isFinal(clz.getModifiers())
```

The modifiers of a class (or field, or method) are represented as a packed-bit `int` in the reflection API. Each possible modifier has its own bit mask, and the `Modifier` class helps in masking out those bits.

You can check for the following modfiers:

- `abstract`
- `final`
- `interface`
- `native`
- `private`
- `protected`
- `public`
- `static`
- `strictfp`
- `synchronized`
- `transient`
- `volatile`

Answer (score 5):

```
Modifier.isFinal(clz.getModifiers())
```

Answer (score 2):

You use [`Class.getModifiers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers--), ideally using the [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class to interpret the return value in a readable way:

```
if (Modifier.isFinal(clz.getModifiers())
```